# Provisioning iPhone on Snow Leopard, XCode 4 and iOS5.1

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ios5, xcode4

I'm new to the whole iOS development thing but I have completed my first app and now wish to deploy to my iPhone for final testing round.

However, I have a yellow dot next to my device and the message tells me that iOS 5.1 is not supported and that I need to get the latest SDK's.

I have done that but still the error persists insisting that the highest iOS i can test is 5.0.

I'm not going to go back to 5.0 on my iPhone as that would just be stupid.

I have the latest updates for Snow Leopard, latest updates for xCode 4.

Anyone know what I need to do for me to be able to use my iPhone?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Xcode 4 max supported iOS is 5.0, as your phone is iOS 5.1 it is not possible to install your app directly with Xcode. You have two solutions:

1/ Either you install Xcode 4.3.2 (iOS 5.1), but you need to install Mac OS X Lion (10.7)

2/ Or create an adhoc version of your app (it is explained on Apple web site), and use this software to install your app on your phone : http://support.apple.com/kb/DL1465?viewlocale=fr_FR&locale=fr_FR

Comment: Yeah I kinda figured that was going to be the answer.  I should have expected Apple would find a way to making that difficult!  Thanks @Niko

Comment: http://support.apple.com/kb/DL1465?viewlocale=en_EN&locale=en_EN for the English version.